# I got pain in my right shoulder for a long playing of piano

Tags: posture, pain

Usually for around over 20mins of playing piano my right shoulder starts to feel pain, especially when playing arpeggios. I felt my right shoulder got more and more tired until painful. I tried to check my shoulder if they had tilted to either side but seems not. I took a photo with a posture which I feel the most relaxed where others will make me feel tired for a long time playing (around 30mins). Does anyone knows the problem?

(But the photo couldn't be uploaded in my app. It saids “sorry something went wrong when trying to upload that image”).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Back hurts after playing piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/94509/back-hurts-after-playing-piano).  Also note, it might be a pinched nerve.  A visit to the doctor and/or physical therapist might be in order.

Comment: Agreed. Could also be caused by tension. Very difficult to fix without seeing in person. Talk to a pianist; talk to a doctor.